# Iteration over Set in React component won't render in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, set, iteration, jsx

I'm trying to iterate over a javascript Set() passed down in props inside a React component. I can't anything to render on the screen with the iteration in place:

```
 {selectedCity.forEach((key, value) => (
          return (
            <Row>
              <Col sm={12} md={6} mdOffset={4} lgOffset={4}>
                <Typography className="hide-mobile" h3>
                  TICKET PRICE FOR IN-STATE:
                </Typography>
                <Typography h3>{value.name}</Typography>
                <TicketPriceInput
                  onChange={e => {
                    setConcertDetails('price', e.target.value);
                    detectInputChange(e);
                  }}
                  value={price}
                  name="price"
                  isPriceChanged={isPriceChanged}
                />
                <OutPriceLabel className="hide-mobile">
                  <Typography h3>TICKET PRICE FOR OUT-OF-STATE:</Typography>
                  <Typography h3 bold className="hide-mobile">
                    {outLocationPrice()}
                  </Typography>
                </OutPriceLabel>

                <FootNote>
                  <Typography medium spaced className="hide-mobile">
                    *After the first 20 tickets anyone located in-state can
                    purchase tickets at the regular ticket price you set.
                  </Typography>
                </FootNote>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          );
        ))}
```

I've done this plenty of times with an Array or Object with `map()` or `Object.keys()` and it's worked.

Comment: after `=>` on first line you have ` ( ..... )` it should be `{ .... }`

Comment: the more significant problem is that `forEach` returns nothing (or rather `undefined`), so this won't render anything. The JS `Set` api doesn't have anything like `map`, so it looks like you have to use [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/entries) first and then map over that. Or convert the set to an array first and use `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Set.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) method iterates the Set's values, but doesn't return like other `.forEach()` methods.

One option is to push the created elements to an array, and then return the array:

```
const renderSelectedCity = selectedSet => {
  const rendered = [];

  selectedSet.forEach(value => {
    rendered.push(
      <Row key={value.id}>
      // your JSX
      </Row>
    );
  });

  return rendered;
};
```

And then you can use it by calling the function, and supplying the Set:

```
{renderSelectedCity(selectedCity)}
```

The other option is to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#relation_with_array_objects) the Set to an array, iterate the array with `Array.map()` that would return a new array of rendered elements:

```
{[...selectedCity].map(value => (
  <Row key={value.id}>
  // your JSX
  </Row>
))}
```

You can also use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create a JSX array from the `Set`:

```
Array.from(selectedCity, value => (
  <Row key={value.id}>
  // your JSX
  </Row>
))}
```

Comment: Ended up using the spread operator. Great solution.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `map`. That's because `map` will return the component, but `forEach` will not.
`map` is an array method, not available in Sets. but you can easily map over the set by using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (which will convert the `Set` into an `Array`)

```
Array.from(selectedCity).map(...)
```